# Setting JLabels in rows and placing the equivalent JTextField right next to it

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jtextfield, layout-manager

I am trying to create 4 `JLabel` components 4 `JTextfield` components for my Swing based application. I am adding these lables and text fields in one of the many panels of the application.

The class for this panel is as follows:

```
public class CustomerInfoPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

        private Car[] carList;
        private CarSalesSystem carSystem;
        private int currentIndex = 0;
        private JLabel headingLabel = new JLabel("Enter your details and let us find a car for you");
        private JLabel ageLabel = new JLabel("Age");
        private JLabel genderLabel = new JLabel("Gender");
        private JLabel incomeLabel = new JLabel("Income");
        private JLabel interestLabel = new JLabel("Age");

        private JButton searchButton = new JButton("Search");
        private JButton resetButton = new JButton("Reset");
        private JButton previousButton = new JButton("Previous");
        private JButton nextButton = new JButton("Next");

        //text fields
        private JTextField ageTextField = new JTextField();
        private JTextField genderTextField = new JTextField();
        private JTextField incomeTextField = new JTextField();
        private JTextField interestTextField = new JTextField();

        private JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        private JPanel agePanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        private JPanel searchButtonsPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        private JPanel navigateButtonsPanel = new JPanel();
        private CarDetailsComponents carComponents = new CarDetailsComponents();

        /**
         * @param carSys links to a CarSalesSystem object
         * @param dest where the panel will be displayed on the main frame
         */
        public CustomerInfoPanel(CarSalesSystem carSys)
        {
            carSystem = carSys;
            Insets currentInsets;
            GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints;
            setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 20));
            topPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(topPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

            previousButton.addActionListener(this);
            nextButton.addActionListener(this);
            resetButton.addActionListener(this);
            searchButton.addActionListener(this);

            String currentFont = ageLabel.getFont().getName();
            currentInsets =  new Insets(0, 10, 0, 30);

            ageLabel.setFont(new Font(currentFont, Font.BOLD, 12));
            gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
            gridBagConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            gridBagConstraints.insets = currentInsets;
            agePanel.add(ageLabel, gridBagConstraints);

            genderLabel.setFont(new Font(currentFont, Font.BOLD, 12));
            gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
            gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
            gridBagConstraints.gridy = 1;
            gridBagConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            gridBagConstraints.insets = currentInsets;
            agePanel.add(genderLabel, gridBagConstraints);

            incomeLabel.setFont(new Font(currentFont, Font.BOLD, 12));
            gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
            gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
            gridBagConstraints.gridy = 2;
            gridBagConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            gridBagConstraints.insets = currentInsets;
            agePanel.add(incomeLabel, gridBagConstraints);

            interestLabel.setFont(new Font(currentFont, Font.BOLD, 12));
            gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
            gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
            gridBagConstraints.gridy = 3;
            gridBagConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            gridBagConstraints.insets = currentInsets;
            agePanel.add(interestLabel, gridBagConstraints);

            gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
            gridBagConstraints.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
            gridBagConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            gridBagConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
            agePanel.add(ageTextField, gridBagConstraints);

            gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
            gridBagConstraints.gridx = 1;
            gridBagConstraints.gridy = 1;
            gridBagConstraints.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
            gridBagConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            gridBagConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
            agePanel.add(genderTextField, gridBagConstraints);

            gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
            gridBagConstraints.gridx = 1;
            gridBagConstraints.gridy = 2;
            gridBagConstraints.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
            gridBagConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            gridBagConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
            agePanel.add(incomeTextField, gridBagConstraints);

            gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
            gridBagConstraints.gridx = 1;
            gridBagConstraints.gridy = 3;
            gridBagConstraints.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
            gridBagConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            gridBagConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
            agePanel.add(interestTextField, gridBagConstraints);


            searchButtonsPanel.add(searchButton);
            searchButtonsPanel.add(resetButton);
            navigateButtonsPanel.add(previousButton);
            navigateButtonsPanel.add(nextButton);
            agePanel.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder(new Insets(0, 5, 0, 0)));
            searchButtonsPanel.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder(new Insets(0, 5, 0, 0)));

            headingLabel.setAlignmentX(0.5f);

            topPanel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
            topPanel.add(headingLabel);
            topPanel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
            topPanel.add(agePanel);
            topPanel.add(searchButtonsPanel);
            topPanel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(15));
            carComponents.add(navigateButtonsPanel, "Center");
            carComponents.setVisible(false);

            add(topPanel, "North");
            add(carComponents, "Center");
        }
```

But when I execute the above code, I end up getting the following[image: output]

As you can clearly see from the image that the text field and labels are not positioned properly. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `agePanel` is using a `FlowLayout`, but you're trying to specify `GridBagConstraints` to the components you're adding to it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `agePanel` is using a `FlowLayout`, but you're supplying `GridBagConstraints` to it when you're adding your components.  You need to make up you mind over which layout manager you want to use.

Start by changing the layout manager for `agePanel` to a `GridBagLayout`

```
private JPanel agePanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
```

Then supply a column hint the `JTextField`

```
private JTextField ageTextField = new JTextField(10);
private JTextField genderTextField = new JTextField(10);
private JTextField incomeTextField = new JTextField(10);
private JTextField interestTextField = new JTextField(10);
```

[image: Hello fields]

Take a closer look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) and focus on the differences between the different layout managers

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I was a bit confused between a FlowLayout and a GridLayout but now I think things are pretty clear.

Comment: aaach (and I don't expect a/any reply) JButton labeled with Reset isn't  aligned to the column with JTextFields, plus one

Comment: @Kishore pandey don't forget to up_vote and accept his answer

Answer (score -1):

If you want to develop customized user interface you have to use below method and bind controls freely where ever you want **setLayout(null)** and use **setBounds(x, y, width, height)** method to bind controls without using any Layout Manager.

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: agree with Mads comment and downvoting too

Comment: If we are talking about Modern UI, we have to use SWT or the latest one Java FX. And I have given this answer because the guys is stuck with layout manager as we can see in code. And as per my understanding AWT/Swing are the oldest terminologies to build UI in java.

Comment: *"AWT/Swing are the oldest terminologies to build UI in java"* so is SWT.  Even in JavaFX, you should be using layout managers.  Absolute positioning just creates a load more work which the layout managers have already solved and as a general, (absolute layouts) are never the right choice